# Adding a Border Dynamically to an Image on an HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I've got a canvas that includes images, I'm re-drawing 1 pixel lower each time to give the effect of falling.  I've got the images in an array and I just place them 1 pixel lower without recreating the image.

Is it possible to add a border dynamically to images that reach a certain point and if so, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, all you have to do is draw a path outside the image and call `ctx.stroke()` to make the border.

So say the image has the coordinates `x` and `y`, with a width and height of `w` and `h`, you just do:

```
ctx.rect(x, y, w, h);
ctx.stroke();
```

Want a different colored border?

```
ctx.strokeStyle = 'blue';
```

Thicker?

```
ctx.lineWidth = 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know your images' size and location and as you draw them you probably do, You can use the `.rect` canvas method to draw a rectangle around the image.